# How to package code change in multiply src files using Git

Tags: git, github

I am a beginner for Git/Github.
My company has an internal version control tool developed by themselves. In this tool, there is a conception "package". If you make code change in single/many source files when working on one task,  you must package them into a changelist (package, looks like "shelve" in TFS). Developers review and checkin changelist rather than files.
I search some beginner post, most of commands have counterparts to internal tool. But I can't find command that looks like "package" of internal tool.
Does "Package" exists in Git? Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called `git commit`. It's a list of changes to one or multiple files, as an atomic operation. It also contains metadata, like committer, date, time, parent commit(s).

Comment: If I modified two files under dir but I hope only commit one of them, How can I do it?

Comment: You normally have to stage files for the commit before, with the `git add` command. You have the freedom to add only a subset of the changed files. Or you can commit all changed tracked files in one go with the `git commit -a` command.